# Add a background image to a JPanel that repeats

Tags: java, swing

I'm using an animated gif and that it repeats to fill the entire window.

I've read that overriding the `paintComponent` method will allow me to draw a single image; is there any way that I can draw that image multiple times to fill up an arbitrarily sized space?

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227423/java-swing-background-image) only that your scenario is with JPanel

Comment: It looks like you had cast a duplicate vote at the time you first posted this question, which aged away as the question failed to collect enough votes. For some reason, users are prevented from casting the same vote again even after it's aged away. I've closed the question for you now.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [TexturePaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html). Here is a basic [demo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/TexturePaintDemo.htm). You can find a more complete example of `TexturePaint` in this sample [chapter](http://oreilly.com/catalog/java2d/chapter/ch04.html) from [Java 2D Graphics](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565924840.do) book.